# Cucumber correct step definition file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have the following step:

```
Then I should see an error message
```

with identical definition:

```
Then /^I should see an error message$/ do
    page.should have_selector('#flash_alert', text: 'Invalid')
end
```

in two different features: **admin_sign_in.feature** and **user_login.feature**.

Where should I place the definition properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a new file.

Call it something like `flash_message_steps.rb` or `error_steps.rb` or anything else you like.  I would suggest something generic though, calling it `admin_steps.rb` or `user_steps.rb` doesn't really make sense.  All the files in the `step_definitions` folder are auto-loaded.  Just be sure to define it once only as duplicate definitions for the same step will raise an ambiguity error.

I would also recommend making your step more generic, something like:

```
Then /^I should see an error message containing "([^\"]*)"$/ do |message|
    page.should have_selector('#flash_alert', text: message)
end
```

You can then use the same definition to test multiple errors:

```
Then I should see an error message containing "Invalid"

Then I should see an error message containing "You must sign in first"
```